# Make variable's data type match column's data type

Tags: sql-server

A local variable's data type needs to match the data type of an existing table column.

In the past, I would look up the column's data type and manually match, like so:

```
-- schema follows...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [valueholder] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)

...
-- manually set data type to match above
DECLARE @tempvalueholder AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

The trouble is, if the schema changes somewhere along the line, I'd have to manually look up and update.

Assuming the column and table names remain constant, is there some way to tie a local variable's data type to a column's data type?

I know how to get the data type in a way similar to this, but can't figure out how to hook up to a variable declaration:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='testtable'
AND COLUMN_NAME='valueholder'
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: "if the schema changes somewhere along the line" yes but this is (should) be part of a managed change process and subject to testing, so you should be able as part of that process to identify which code items are impacted by your changes and plan to change them, and testing ought to pick up any mistakes or omissions. It requires a reasonable level of knowledge of the system you're working on, although sometimes tools can help you identify matches and dependencies in your source code. This seems like a fairly normal part of application and database programming, tbh

Comment: If you are going to be having dynamic data types for the variable, you could consider using the [sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql) data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create "DECLARE @VariableName DATATYPE" dynamically. This means that the variable and the rest of your code should be in the scope of the dynamic SQL. If this fits your needs, you can try this:

```
DECLARE
    @DataType1 VARCHAR(16)
    , @DataType2 VARCHAR(16)
    , @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT
    @DataType1 = UPPER(DATA_TYPE)
    , @DataType2 = 
        CASE
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar')) THEN CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')')
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')) THEN CASE WHEN (CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1) THEN CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(MAX)') ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')') END
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric')) THEN CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', NUMERIC_PRECISION, ', ', NUMERIC_SCALE, ')')
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE = 'float') THEN CASE WHEN (NUMERIC_PRECISION = 53) THEN UPPER(DATA_TYPE) ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', NUMERIC_PRECISION, ')') END
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE = 'real') THEN CASE WHEN (NUMERIC_PRECISION = 24) THEN UPPER(DATA_TYPE) ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', NUMERIC_PRECISION, ')') END
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE = 'image') THEN NULL
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE = 'time') THEN CASE WHEN (DATETIME_PRECISION = 7) THEN UPPER(DATA_TYPE) ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', DATETIME_PRECISION, ')') END
            WHEN (DATA_TYPE = 'varbinary') THEN CASE WHEN (CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1) THEN CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(MAX)') ELSE CONCAT(UPPER(DATA_TYPE), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')') END
            ELSE UPPER(DATA_TYPE)
        END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName';

IF(@DataType2 IS NULL)
    BEGIN RAISERROR (N'Data type %s is invalid for local variables.', 16, 1, @DataType1); END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @DynamicSQL += N'
DECLARE @VariableName ' + @DataType2 + ';'

        SET @DynamicSQL += N'
SET @VariableName = 15;

SELECT @VariableName AS [@VariableName];
';

        EXEC (@DynamicSQL);
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

unlike Oracle this is not supported in sql-server.
The only thing you can do is when the schema of a table changes, find all procedures, triggers, functions that access this table and check/correct the declaration.

Here is a small query that helps you find all procedures, functions and triggers where that table is used :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%MyTableName%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using a temp table which will have exactly the same structure of the originating table.

So even table columns' data types are changed, your stored procedure codes will not be affected.

But it has also coding overload for developers

Here is a sample

```
create procedure TestTable10_readbyId (@Id bigint)
as
begin

DECLARE @tempvalueholder AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select * into #t from TestTable10 where 1 = 0
insert into #t (Id) values (@Id)

update #t
set valueholder = TestTable10.valueholder
from #t
inner join TestTable10 on TestTable10.Id = #t.Id 
and TestTable10.Id = @Id

select @tempvalueholder = valueholder
from TestTable10
where Id = @Id

select @tempvalueholder as valueholder
select valueholder from #t
end
```

You see I have maintained both methods

One is using a data variable declaration
Other is creating a temp table, which generates logically a variable for each column in the select list

Of course we need a row with NULL values for the second solution.

I actually don't prefer this method because you have to think all those during coding. So I have inserted a dummy row with null values but only the PK field that I believe it will be useful in following code blocks

Instead of returning a variable by setting its value first, I update the temp table column and then return this row column in this example.